# Unable to extend, create and attach openstack volume to an instance

Tags: lvm, openstack, cinder

I am running Ocata openstack on Ubuntu 16 and trying to extend an existing volume from 100GB to 250GB by following the link:
https://docs.openstack.org/cinder/rocky/cli/cli-manage-volumes.html

After running fdisk -l I do not see anything

I tried to create a new volume but received the error in the image attached. This does not allow me to attach the vol to the instance either.

[Vol Creation error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMPEP.png)

I checked the following:

[vgdisplay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ak2jz.png)

```
root@block-srv:~# vgdisplay cinder-volumes
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               cinder-volumes
  System ID
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  833
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                69
  Open LV               23
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               5.38 TiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              1409666
  Alloc PE / Size       1408256 / 5.37 TiB
  Free  PE / Size       1410 / 5.51 GiB
  VG UUID               r4q9aH-ebVE-Q2SF-iqSX-DyN5-fify-BUODVY
```

and noticed that the free PE size is 5.51GiB.

I have tried to delete some volumes that has "Error" status as shown in the attached image, I am still getting the same error.

Please can someone assist me with how to troubleshoot this and/or know

- if this is a space issue or
- how to resolve the ability to extend or create a new volume successfully.

Thank you

Comment: Can you replace the images in the question with text? You probably need to scan that disk inside the instance.

Comment: I would also assume that it's a space issue. Your cinder-volume node seems to have run out of it so you either need to add more storage and extend the VG or you need to delete some volumes. But that just a guess based on the few pieces of information.

Comment: @berndbausch I have added the text version of the vgdisplay command

I have deleted some volumes, I am stil seeing no changes in the size of the volumes. Please how do I delete volumes to be able to reflect the free size

Comment: Regarding the error volume: If you have 5Gb free space, my first thought is that you can't create a 250GB volume, except if you use thin provisioning.

Comment: Regarding the size of the attached volume: Did you scan the volume in the instance, and how?

Comment: @berndbausch I used "fdisk -l" command to check for the disk. Pls can you explain how to delete volumes to be able to create more space for the VG? thanks

Comment: `openstack volume delete` or click the DELETE button in the GUI.

Comment: @berndbausch Thank you for your assistance and apologies for late response. I had to delete some unused volumes and was able to expand the volume on the instance.